# Extract specific line of code using awk (or non-awk) from a log file

Tags: awk, sed, extract

I am trying to find a way to extract scripts from the log file generated.

I am stuck at a place where a command calls for multiple files and the script separates them with a trailing "\" for line continuity. For example, a sample script is:

```
my_command -option \
file1 \
file2 \
file3
my_command2 .. ..
```

It looked easy but somehow the trick is not hitting me at this point.
Please help.
Every line in the log starts with a specific identifier for command, like:

```
:: Script_Command:: my_command -option \
:: file1 \
:: file2 \
:: file3 
:: Info lines....
:: More info lines ...
:: Script_Command:: my_command2 ... ..
:: Info lines ...
```

So I used:

```
awk '/Script_Command/ {print }'
```

And then I tried to combine it with a if condition with:

```
awk '/Script_Command/ {print substr(length(),1)}'
```

But the entire thing is not falling in place.
Please help.

Edit:
The closest I got is here:

```
awk '{if ($NF=="\\" ||  == "Script_Command::") print ;}' file
```

It still leaves the file3 line as it does not match anything.

Pure intention is:
1. When Script_Command is matched, print line.
2. When "\" is matched, print the next line.
3. When both are matched, print line and next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working with following command:

```
awk '/\\/ && /Script_Command/ {print $0;getline;print $0;next} /Script_Command/ {print $0;next} /\\/ {getline;print $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use sed for this:

```
sed -n '/Script_Command/ {:a;/\\$/!be;N;ba;:e;p;}'
```

Breakdown

```
                           # -n disables auto printing.
sed -n '/Script_Command/ { # Match regex
  :a                       # Define label 'a'
  /\\$/!be                 # Goto 'e' unless pattern space ends with \
  N                        # Append next line to pattern space
  ba                       # Goto 'a'
  :e                       # Define label 'e'
  p                        # Print pattern space
}'
```

You can add `[[:space:]]*` to `/\\$!be` if you want to read lines ending in slash followed zero or more spaces:

```
/\\[[:space:]]*$/!be
```

Comment: This solution looks promising. When tried, at first it says:

    be: Event not found.                                            

Then in next try, I get:

    sed: -e expression #1, char 20: unknown command: `;'            

I have GNU sed version 4.2.1

Comment: Remember to quote the script? RIght now `!` gets expanded, which is shouldn't: `sed -n '/Script_Command/ {:a;/\\$/!be;N;ba;:e;p;}'`

Comment: Yes I am doing that.

Comment: To clarify, it have nothing to do with sed, but your shell that choose to expand `!be` via a search though your history. If not found you get: `Event not found`. This will expand to nothing, making the next call fail in a new way. Make your your shell doesn't expand sed meta characters, but either wrapping the script in single quotes, or disabling history expansion: `set +H`

Answer (score 0):

If each continues line starts with `::` one can use awk like this:

```
awk '!/^::/ { p = 0 }           # Set p = 0 if line does not start with ::
      /Script_Command/{ p = 1 } # Set p = 1 when line contains Script_Command
      p'                        # Print if p is truly
```

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. Every line starts with :: so just filtering :: will not work.

Comment: Edited my example to make it more precise. I get the point, but I need to extract the next lines where trailing "\" is present for every line even if "Script_Command" is not there in that line. Thanks